# C# - How to remove all color except black from an Image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have some scanned image. I want to drop all color except black.
Problem is black color is not always rgb(0,0,0). So how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: So you just want to get a black image? lol

Comment: Black is *always* `rgb(255,255,255)`. What you want is not keep black, it's keep dark parts, right?

Comment: Do you want to replace all others with white?

Comment: Yes I want to keep dark part

Comment: @Thomas actually, black is always `rgb(0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I'm colorblind. JK, kudos for you :)

Comment: What do you consider "black" for this image then? And @Thomas If you can't discern pure white from pure black you're not colorblind, you're blind :)

Comment: You can use if (pixelColor.GetBrightness() < 0.3) .. or some other limit. Or adjust contrast and gamma with a [ColorMatrix](http://blog.bee-eee.com/2008/01/23/c-adjusting-brightnesscontrast-and-gamma-of-an-image/)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(@"YourPath");
const float limit = 0.3f;
for (int i = 0; i < myBitmap.Width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myBitmap.Height; j++)
    {
        Color c = myBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
        if (c.GetBrightness() > limit)
        {
            myBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
myBitmap.Save(@"YourNewPath");
```

And play with `limit` to get what you want.

Comment: A brief explaination might be warranted here.

Comment: This is a great share but if you want a png image do it like this myBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Transparent); then save image as png format. (myBitmap.Save(yourpath,ImageFormat.Png)) Just for the future developer.